# NSJSONSerialization Exception with german umlaut

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

i try to convert my object to a json string, without umlauts its working fine but when i type a text with "ä" or "ü" im getting this error:

```
ExceptionType = "System.ArgumentException";
Message = "Ein ung\U00fcltiges Objekt wurde \U00fcbergeben. Erwartet wurde \":\" oder \"}\".
```

this is my code:

```
-(Buchungsergebnis*)sendeBuchung:(NSString *)Buchung vomWebservice:(NSString *)WebServiceURL
{
//Erstellt einen Request

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:WebServiceURL]];

[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSData *reqData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[Buchung UTF8String] length:[Buchung length]];
[request setHTTPBody:reqData];

NSURLResponse *response =[[NSURLResponse alloc]init];
NSError *error;
//Führt den Befehl aus
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (data ==nil)
{
    NSLog(@"Login Error: %@",error);
    return false;
}
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init ];
dic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",dic);

NSMutableDictionary *result = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
result = [dic objectForKey:@"d"] ;

Buchungsergebnis *ergebnis = [[Buchungsergebnis alloc]init];
ergebnis.result =[[result objectForKey:@"result"]boolValue];
ergebnis.message =[result objectForKey:@"message"];


return ergebnis;
}
```

and here is the json:

> {"thema":"Test with umlauts \n\nÖffne die tür","personenanzahl":"4","vondatum":"17.12.2013  09:00","veranstalteremail":"asjgdl@dgs.de","bisdatum":"17.12.2013  10:30","dienstleistungen":[],"teilnehmer":[],"veranstaltertelefon":"","veranstalter":"blagojevic domenik","bestuhlungsid":"377","benutzername":"dbl"}

how can i prevent this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is valid (as can be tested on http://jsonlint.com).

But this is problematic:

```
NSData *reqData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[Buchung UTF8String] length:[Buchung length]];
```

because `[Buchung length]` returns the number of (Unicode) *characters* in the string,
which is different from the number of UTF-8 *bytes* for non-ASCII characters such as umlauts.
Better use

```
NSData *reqData = [Buchung dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Or use `NSJSONSerialization` to create the JSON, which gives you an `NSData` object
instead of a string.

You might also have to set the HTTP Content-length explicitly, I am not sure if that
is necessary:

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [reqData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```

Answer (score 0):

try using:
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
(use NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves instead of kNilOptions)

I'm using this with data containing Chinese, Spanish, Hindi languages. It's working fine for me.